# tableView as subview in a semi-transparent view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, subview, alpha

I'm developing a little iOS component and I have a problem with a semi-transparent view with subviews. This is my scenario:
- one view with a semi-transparent background using `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha]`
- a little `UITableView`, with `alpha = 1.0`, added as a subview to the semi-transparent view
- some other subviews

Everything works well but the problem raises when the `UITableView` is scrolled up or down, in fact the area of the semi-transparent view around the `UITableView` loses its transparency becoming darker than its original background color.

Here's an image to explain the problem:
[image]

Look at the space with the two arrows...

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you so much for your attention!

**Update:**
Some code:

```
_alertBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_alertBg.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
_alertBg.frame = CGRectMake((_bgView.frame.size.width - 240) / 2, (_bgView.frame.size.height - 260) / 2, 240, 260);
_alertBg.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
_alertBg.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
_alertBg.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
_alertBg.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
_alertBg.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
_alertBg.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
_alertBg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[_bgView addSubview:_alertBg];

_table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_table.frame = CGRectMake(10, _titleLabel.frame.origin.y + _titleLabel.frame.size.height + 12, _alertBg.frame.size.width - 20, 150);
_table.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
_table.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_table.delegate = self;
_table.dataSource = self;
[_alertBg addSubview:_table];
```

From the code above, `self.backgroundColor` is something like `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.7]`

Comment: Might help to see how these views are created, CGRect information.  IB or programmatic construction?

Comment: Everything is done using simple views and some QuartzCore code, without IB or CGRect... I've edited the post and added some code

Comment: @matteodv please add some code of cellForRawAtIndexPath method and post comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the available code in a test project, and got the same problem as you have. Commenting out `_alertBg.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;` fixes the issue for me. Maybe someone can clarify why is this an issue, I have limited experience with QuartzCore.

EDIT: Okay, inched closer to the real reason. It seems that if you don't have set the `_alertBg.layer.shadowPath` property all kinds of crazy things happen when you scroll the table (my guess here is that the table scroll calls a redraw of the `_alertBg` and the shadow redrawing gets called in quick succession far too many times and you get those visual artifacts).

Adding a `shadowPath` fixes the problem, so the layer code for the `_alertBg` should be as following:

```
_alertBg.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
_alertBg.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
_alertBg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.7].CGColor;
_alertBg.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
_alertBg.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);
_alertBg.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
_alertBg.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_alertBg.bounds].CGPath;
_alertBg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Just fix the `shadowPath` to your liking and you should be ready to go.

PS: On my Google-quest I found [this excellent blog post](http://d3signerd.com/deep-dive-into-calayer-shadows/) about shadows, it might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe match the background colour of tableView with _alertBg?

Answer (score 0):

Its may be problem of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

just try this..., set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` like bellow in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableViewController` delegate method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Also see my this answer may be you can get some idea from this..

[iPhone Hide/Show labels in Uitableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855445/iphone-hide-show-labels-in-uitableview-cell)