# iPhone Hide/Show labels in Uitableview cell

Tags: iphone

I am expanding cell on tapping a cell.
Now i want to hide older labels and needs to add new labels.

On hiding a cell contents, it hides the contents from every reusable cell.
(like on selecting cell 1 i want to hide older label and show new labels for cell 1, but it hides labels from 1, 6, 11.. row)

I am not able to find the solution.

I am using this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    

        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

        // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
        NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];        

        [self.newsTableview beginUpdates];

        UITableViewCell *tableviewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[tableviewCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[tableviewCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView *)[tableviewCell.contentView viewWithTag:102];

         if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
         {          
             label.hidden = YES;
             imageView1.hidden = YES;
             textView.hidden = YES;           
         }        

        [self.newsTableview endUpdates];                       


    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
}
```

Please help..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` like bellow

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

or assign different identifier like bellow...

```
   NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I think you use only one Cell Identifier like this. When you change something, it effects all of them. Try using different identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I able to fix it using Paras suggestion:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```