# Added view in UITableViewCell getting cleared after scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am adding horizontal scrollview  with images  in UITableView cell on selection .On selection cell expanded to show scroll view . When i scrolled up or down added scrollView getting cleared .How to persist table view contain on scrolling?

Comment: paste your cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: post code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` like bellow

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Comment: @swapnil see my this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855445/iphone-hide-show-labels-in-uitableview-cell

Answer (score 0):

problem might be that you are reusing the cells via **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**, if this is the case make sure you do not add scroll view every time cell loaded in to memory. Moreover if you add some code snippiest it would help to understand the actual problem